# Solving the continuous mice problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, puzzle

The classic Mice Problem considers 4 mice standing on the four vertices of a square, and at some point every mouse starts running after its clockwise neighbour in a clockwise manner.

It is not too difficult to prove that if the mice change their direction every fixed amount of time/distance traveled, then their paths are going to be line segments that approximate a logarithmic spiral.

However it seems to me that the spiral's properties depends heavily on the "sampling rate," and I'd like to find a solution for the general, continuous case (so their paths aren't straight at any point, because their targets keep moving). I tried to write the proper differential equations, but they seem too difficult for me to solve; has this problem been addressed before?

Comment: Can you go the other way around? Since the uniqueness of solution is guarantied, can you show that a logarithmic spiral solves the necessary equations?

Comment: @JonathanY.: Thank you for your comment. It is a very interesting idea; I have not considered it, but will shortly. (Why is the solution unique, by the way?)

Comment: @Mickey: The speeds of the mice should be constant (and equal). The direction of travel of a given mouse is uniquely determined by the position of its clockwise neighbor, but this uniquely determines the given mouse's position, since at all times the four mice will be on vertices of a square with the same center as the original square. Hence, a given mouse's velocity depends only on its position, so we have a differential initial value problem, which has a unique solution (if any).

Comment: Here is a paper which may help http://math.berkeley.edu/~preskill/math53/notes_c10_problemplus4.pdf

Comment: @MarkBennet: Thanks, very interesting. So it doesn't depend on the bugs' speed?

Comment: Here is another link http://www.cut-the-knot.org/Curriculum/Geometry/FourTurtles.shtml

Comment: @MickeyMouse If you think about it, if all the speeds are equal, the effect of increasing the speed will be to go faster along the same path.

Comment: @MarkBennet I guess it does make sense. What I am trying to understand now is why the theta has coefficient 1 in the exponent factor, while when I trace the very closely related whirls I get different coefficients.

Comment: In addition ot @Cameron's comment, observe that the mice are always at the vertices of a square centered at the original center *and* that the moving direction is always along the square edges, that is at an angle of $45^\circ$ against the line center-mouse. So you immediately arrive at the solution that in polar coordinates we have $r'=r$, hence $r$ is exponential in $\phi$.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Thanks, that is a very nice observation, which leads to two more questions -- what if there are n mice, and how does one intuitively explain the geometrical meaning of r'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think one should use a time-dependant curve, to avoid division by zero.

Now let there be $n > 1$ entities chasing after one another in a circle like fashion. At the beginning they shall be positioned at the vertices of a regular polygon with $n$ edges.

This set up is symmetric to a rotation of $2π/n$. So the $n$ solution paths will also be symmetric in this manner. Let the centre of the rotation be the centre of an Cartesian coordinate system. Choose a single entity and name its path $φ: ℝ \ni t ↦ φ(t) \in ℝ^2$ with polar coordinates $α: ℝ → ℝ$ and $r: ℝ → ℝ$ such that $φ = r(\cos α, \sin α)$.

The centre, the position of the entity, $φ(t)$, and the position of the next entity, $φ(t)$ rotated by $2π/n$ (say $R_nφ(t)$), form an isosceles triangle. The entity is moving in the direction from $φ(t)$ to $R_nφ(t)$. So the angle between the vectors $φ(t)$ and $φ'(t)$ is
$$2π/n + \frac{π - 2π/n}{2} = π\frac{2/n + 1}{2} = π(\frac1n + \frac12)$$
This means $$⟨φ', φ⟩ = ||φ'||\cdot||φ||\cos π(\frac1n+\frac12) ≕ ||φ'||\cdot||φ||\cdot C$$
where $-1≤C<0$. Now $$2⟨φ', φ⟩ = ⟨φ, φ⟩' = (||φ||^2)' = 2||φ||\cdot||φ||'$$ so that $$ ||φ||' = C||φ'||$$ This velocity is assumed to be constant $||φ'|| ≕ v > 0$. Together with the above we get $r' = Cv$. So $r = r_0 + Cvt$. Using the polar coordinates we calculate
$$φ' = r'(\cos α, \sin α) + rα'(-\sin α, \cos α)$$ The two summands of $φ'$ are orthogonal so $$v = ||φ'|| = -r' + rα' = -Cv + rα'$$ This in turn gives us $$α' = \frac{v(1+C)}{r} = \frac{v(1+C)}{r_0 + Cvt}$$ if $C > -1$, i.e. $n > 2$ $$α = \frac{v(1+C)}{Cv}\ln r = (\frac1C+1)\ln r\\r = \exp\left(\frac{α}{\frac1C+1}\right)$$ when we start at $α_0 = 0$. For $n=2$ we have $C=-1, α' = 0$ and $α$ is constant.

Comment: 7 years late here, but what is $\varphi '$?

Comment: Oh boy, it has been some time since I did anything like this :-D. Here, I'm pretty sure, $\varphi'$ means $d\varphi/dt$.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve the corresponding differential equation without even considering polar coordinates.

Let's assume that the mice are at the four corners $(1,1)^T$, $(1,-1)^T$, $(-1,-1)^T$ and $(-1,1)^T$.
Denote by $x_i(t)$ for $\,i=1,2,3,4\,$ the trajectories of the mice corresponding to each starting corner.
Then:
$$x_i'(t)=\frac{x_{i+1}(t)-x_i(t)}{||x_{i+1}(t)-x_i(t)||}\quad\mbox{with}\quad x_5=x_1.$$

Due to symmetry, $x_{i+1}(t)$ is $x_i(t)$ up to a 90-degree rotation, i.e.
$$x_{i+1}(t)=\begin{pmatrix}0 & 1\\-1 & 0\end{pmatrix}x_i(t).$$
Hence, we can focus on $\,i=1$ (the other curves follow from 90-degree rotations).
Let $\,x(t)=x_1(t)$, then
$$x'(t)=\frac{M\,x(t)}{||M\,x(t)||}\quad\mbox{with}\quad M=\begin{pmatrix}-1 & 1\\-1 & -1\end{pmatrix}.$$

Let's solve the following problem first:
$\,x_\ell'(t)=M\,x_\ell(t)\,$ with $\,x_\ell(0)=(1,1)^T.$
This is a linear ODE with the solution:
$$x_\ell(t)=\mathrm{e}^{-t}\begin{pmatrix}\cos(t)+\sin(t)\\\cos(t)-\sin(t)\end{pmatrix}.$$

The solution of the original problem follows now from the ansatz: $\,x(t)=x_\ell(\phi(t))$.
Note $\,||M\,x_h(\phi(t))||=2\,\mathrm{e}^{-\phi(t)}\,$ because $\,\sin^2(t)+\cos^2(t)=1$.
Hence, we need to solve $\,\phi'(t)=\frac{1}{2}\,\mathrm{e}^{\phi(t)}\,$ with $\,\phi(0)=0$.
This is a separable ODE with solution $\,\phi(t)=-\log(1-\frac{t}{2})$.

Overall, we get the solution:
$$x_1(t)=(1-\frac{t}{2})\begin{pmatrix}\cos(\log(1-\frac{t}{2}))-\sin(\log(1-\frac{t}{2}))\\\cos(\log(1-\frac{t}{2}))+\sin(\log(1-\frac{t}{2}))\end{pmatrix}.$$

Comment: Hi!, can someone explain how to solve the linear ODE of Thomas Bernhardt? I can't achieve that part by my own.

Comment: @Aezir The ordinary differential equation $y'(t) = m y(t)$ has solution $y(t) = y_0 e^{mt}$. Analogous to the exponential of a function, one can define the exponential of a matrix, e.g. by an infinite series $\exp(A) := \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{A^n}{n!}$ (provided one shows that such an object makes sense by defining a norm on matrices and showing that series converges which respect to that norm). It can be shown that the derivative of $\exp(tM) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{t^n M^n}{n!}$ is as expected (given by differentiating termwise), and hence $\frac{d}{dt} \exp(tM) = \exp(tM) M$...

Comment: ...This means that the a solution of the matrix DE(system of linear DEs) $x'(t)=Mx(t)$is given by$x(t)=\exp(tM)x_0$,and it can be shown that the solution of a system of linear DEs is unique,and hence we have found the solution.It should be noted that even though one $can$ solve the mice problem without going into polar coordinates, that doesn't mean one should- however if you find staying in Cartesian coordinates appealing then it's worth pointing out that the calculations are much easier if the mice start at $(\pm 1,0)$and$(0,\pm 1)$ instead of $(\pm 1,\pm 1)$(as these corr to roots of unity)